# How to get response behaviour same on POSTMAN as like Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, postman, settimeout

Here below is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write("First \n");

    setTimeout(() => {
        res.end("Done");
    },2000);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000")
})
```

Now, If I access the browser using `http://localhost:3000` then on access URL it shows `First` on the browser and after two seconds it shows `Done`. which is fine.

but when I try this on POSTMAN why it shows

> First
>   Done

together. Can anyone explain the reason for it? Or Is this possible or not to get the same behaviour of response on postman as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are sending chunks back to client with `res.write` these chunks will get rendered as they arrive by the browser resulting in the delay effect you describe.

Currently however Postman does not support this chunking and it waits until it gets the signal the response has ended (from `res.end`). Basically it waits for the entire response before doing something with it.

This might change in upcoming versions of Postman: [Github](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7873)

Edit:

Using the Fetch API those chunks can be accessed like this:

```js
fetch("/")
  // Retrieve its body as ReadableStream
  .then(response => response.body)
  .then(body => {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    const reader = body.getReader();

    reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => console.log(decoder.decode(value)));
    reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => console.log(decoder.decode(value)));
  });
```

(except that you would use the `done` value to generate a loop)

Comment: Is this possible in case of axios?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, you want the same behaviour on the browser ?

Comment: as we are getting a halt on the browser, Is this possible if I call the same URL as API using axios ?

Comment: you will have to check the axios api for that, I am not very familiar with that library

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect how you _could_ do this using just the native fetch api.